# Consulta de datos a SerialPort desde javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, serialport, routes

Estoy trabajando con un proyecto que lee el peso de una balanza continuamente, utilizando SerialPort.
La toma de peso me funciona correctamente. Siempre recibo los datos desde la balanza perfectamente.
El problema que tengo es que yo necesito enviar una peticion y capturar el peso del momento.
Cuando lo hago, obtengo una respuesta, pero si los kilos en la balanza se modifican, siempre obtengo el mismo primer resultado.
A continuacion muestro el codigo utilizado.

```
const { SerialPort } = require ('serialport');
const { ReadlineParser } = require('@serialport/parser-readline');
const express = require ('express');
const app = express();
const portnav = 3000;

app.listen(portnav,()=>{
  console.log('servidor en puerto 3001')
})

const port = new SerialPort({
    path: '/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudRate : 1200,
    //autoOpen: true
}, function(err){
    if(err){
        return console.log('Error: ', err.message);
    }
});
const parser = port.pipe(new ReadlineParser({ delimiter: '\r' }))
parser.on('data',function(data) {
    app.get('/peso', function (req, res) {
        res.send({
            peso : String(data),
        });
    });
   
    console.log(String(data))
});
```

Una vez que ejecuto el servidor, los datos recibidos por el puerto serial, nunca se interrupen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo cuando consulto desde Postman, solo me devuelve el primer valor que recibe, independientemente de si varian los datos recibidos por el puerto serial.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito poder solicitar todas las veces que sea necesario y que me devuelva el valor actual.

¿Alguna idea?.

Muchas gracias!

Nota: intenté haciendo esto:

```
        app.get('/peso', function (req, res) {
        const parser = port.pipe(new ReadlineParser({ delimiter: 
        '\r' }))
        parser.on('data',function(data) {
           res.send({
              peso : String(data),
           });
        });
```

Esto no devuelve valores hasta tanto ejecuto la llamada desde postman, y al hacerlo solo devuelve el valor acutal y recibo un error por consola que cierra la escucha.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: No tengo ni idea cual es la causa del problema porque nunca he trabajado con el puerto serial... pero se me ocurre una idea... que tal si defines una variable global, por ejemplo `peso`. Sacas la definicion de la ruta `get` afuera del parser y le pones que retorne esa variable global `peso`... y en el evento "on data" seteas esa variable global con el datos que te de el puerto? (no lo pongo como respuesta porque es simplemente una idea que depronto creo que podría funcionar... pero no tengo ni idea si sea valida o no.

Comment: Muchas gracias, como comentaron un poco mas abajo y de la mano con lo que me as indicado, pude solucionar el tema. Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás declarando el *handler* de las peticiones HTTP dentro del de los cambios de peso, lo que causa un comportamiento bastante extraño (estás definiendo un *handler* HTTP nuevo en cada lectura del puerto serial, lo que causa que tengas múltiples y por tanto los errores al gestionar la petición).

Así debería funcionar:

```javascript
const { SerialPort } = require('serialport');
const { ReadlineParser } = require('@serialport/parser-readline');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const portnav = 3000;

app.listen(portnav, () => {
    console.log('servidor en puerto 3001')
});

let currentData = 0;
app.get('/peso', function (req, res) {
    res.send({
        peso: String(currentData),
    });
});

const port = new SerialPort({
    path: '/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudRate: 1200
}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Error: ', err.message);
    }
});
const parser = port.pipe(new ReadlineParser({ delimiter: '\r' }))
parser.on('data', data => currentData = data);
```

Comment: Algo así fue lo que propuse en mi comentario, gracias por plasmarlo como respuesta jejejeje ;)